# JavaScript - Array as function parameter is changed in every for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, parameters

My exercise is creating a function that takes two parameters: a multi-dimensional array, and a value. I have to return a new array in which all the sub-array that contain the value is removed. My idea is using nesting  **for** loop to search for the value in every sub-array. If the matching is found, remove the sub-array and end the inner loop. But the code was not runing well and I found a problem as below when debugging:

```js
//Assingment is from FreeCodeCamp
function filteredArray(arr, elem) {
  let newArr = [];
  //my solution start here
  newArr = arr;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
      //debugging
      console.log( "i", i);
      console.log( 'j', j);
      console.log(arr);
      console.log(arr[i]);
      console.log(arr[i][j]);
      //end debugging
      if (arr[i][j] == elem) {
        newArr.shift();   //remove the sub-array
       j = arr[i].length; //end the inner loop
      } 
      console.log('newArr',newArr);
    }
  }
  //my solution end here
  return newArr;
}

// change code here to test different cases:
console.log(filteredArray([[3, 2, 3], [1, 6, 3], [3, 13, 26], [19, 3, 9]], 3));
```

The result is:

```
"i" 0
"j" 0
[[3,2,3],[1,6,3],[3,13,26],[19,3,9]]
[3,2,3]
3
"newArr" [[1,6,3],[3,13,26],[19,3,9]]
"i" 1
"j" 0
[[1,6,3],[3,13,26],[19,3,9]]
[3,13,26]
3
"newArr" [[3,13,26],[19,3,9]]
[[3,13,26],[19,3,9]]
```

The code was run well in the first i = 0 loop. But in the next loop, i = 1, the parameter array is changed. I supposed it to be the input array of the function but turn out, the first sub-array is removed even though I didn't make any change in that array. Can anyone help me explain this?

Comment: When you assign `arr` to `newArr`, you make both variables reference the exact same array; `newArr = arr` does **not** make a copy.

Comment: `newArr` and `arr` are references to the same array. Make a copy if you don't want to modify the original array.

Comment: `newArr.shift();` this always removes the first element. Also, changing an iterable mid-iteration results in undesired behavior, unless you manually adjust for it. Better just build the result up, instead of removing, that saves you trouble adjusting the indices.

Comment: what should happen with empty arrays after filtering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By saying `newArr = arr;`, you are keeping the same reference to original array so any change on one will affect the other. There are ways to copy arrays, one is the spreed operator(`[...arr]`) to make a shallow copy, which is fine for your specific example. Another thing is the `shift()` method will always return or remove from the array the first element. You can use the array `splice()` method to do index based operations on array, like adding, removing or replacing elements.

```js
function filteredArray([...arr], elem) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
      if (arr[i][j] == elem) {
        arr[i].splice(j, 1);
      } 
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(filteredArray([[3, 2, 3], [1, 6, 3], [3, 13, 26], [19, 3, 9]], 3));
```

You may also shorten the step with built in `map()` and `filter()` methods:

```js
filteredArray = (arr, elem) => arr.map( a => a.filter(value => value != elem));

console.log(filteredArray([[3, 2, 3], [1, 6, 3], [3, 13, 26], [19, 3, 9]], 3));
```

EDIT :

The above answer assumed you wanted to remove the element only. Provided you want to remove the sub array containing the element:

```js
function filteredArray([...arr], elem) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
      if (arr[i][j] == elem) {
        arr.splice(i, 1);
        i--;    
        break;
      } 
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(filteredArray([[3, 2, 3], [1, 6, 3], [3, 13, 26], [19, 3, 9]], 3));
console.log(filteredArray([[3, 2, 3], [1, 6, 3], [13, 26], [19, 3, 9]], 3));
```

Or in short:

```js
filteredArray = (arr, elem) => arr.filter( a => !a.includes(elem));

console.log(filteredArray([[3, 2, 3], [1, 6, 3], [3, 13, 26], [19, 3, 9]], 3));
console.log(filteredArray([[3, 2, 3], [1, 6, 3], [13, 26], [19, 3, 9]], 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

To make an array copy, do

```
newArr = arr.slice(0);
```

Comment: While this is a part of the problem, it doesn't fix his function just by itself.

Comment: Thank you!! I'll try to fix my function step by step

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution to your problem (TKol answered it),
consider not using for loops if you don't need the indices

```js
function filteredArray(arr, elem) {
  return arr.filter(row => {
    return !row.includes(elem)
  })
}
console.log(filteredArray([[3, 2, 3], [1, 6, 3], [3, 13, 26], [19, 3, 9]], 3));
console.log(filteredArray([[1, 2, 4], [1, 6, 2], [3, 13, 26], [19, 3, 9]], 3));
```

Comment: This removes entire row, op states only the given value should be removed from the row.

Comment: @Eldar , nope, the subarray itself should be removed:  ```If the matching is found, remove the sub-array```

Comment: Yeap my mistake fail to read.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a recursive approach and filter nested arrays by callign the function again.

```js
function filteredArray(array, element) {
    var result = [],
        i, l, item;

    for (i = 0, l = array.length; i < l; i++) {
        item = array[i];
        if (item === element) continue;
        result.push(Array.isArray(item) ? filteredArray(item, element) : item);
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(filteredArray([[3, 2, 3], [1, 6, 3], [3, 13, 26], [19, 3, 9]], 3));
```